# How to connect Python to Db2

Tags: python, db2

Is there a way to connect Python to Db2?

Answer (score 37):

The documentation is difficult to find, and once you find it, it's pretty abysmal. Here's what I've found over the past 3 hours.

You need to install `ibm_db` using `pip`, as follows:

```
pip install ibm_db
```

You'll want to create a connection object. [The documentation is here.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=framework-application-development-db)

Here's what I wrote:

```
from ibm_db import connect
# Careful with the punctuation here - we have 3 arguments.
# The first is a big string with semicolons in it.
# (Strings separated by only whitespace, newlines included,
#  are automatically joined together, in case you didn't know.)
# The last two are emptry strings.
connection = connect('DATABASE=<database name>;'
                     'HOSTNAME=<database ip>;'  # 127.0.0.1 or localhost works if it's local
                     'PORT=<database port>;'
                     'PROTOCOL=TCPIP;'
                     'UID=<database username>;'
                     'PWD=<username password>;', '', '')
```

Next you should know that commands to `ibm_db` never actually give you results. Instead, you need to call one of the `fetch` methods on the command, repeatedly, to get the results. I wrote this helper function to deal with that.

```
def results(command):
    from ibm_db import fetch_assoc

    ret = []
    result = fetch_assoc(command)
    while result:
        # This builds a list in memory. Theoretically, if there's a lot of rows,
        # we could run out of memory. In practice, I've never had that happen.
        # If it's ever a problem, you could use
        #     yield result
        # Then this function would become a generator. You lose the ability to access
        # results by index or slice them or whatever, but you retain
        # the ability to iterate on them.
        ret.append(result)
        result = fetch_assoc(command)
    return ret  # Ditch this line if you choose to use a generator.
```

Now with that helper function defined, you can easily do something like get the information on all the tables in your database with the following:

```
from ibm_db import tables

t = results(tables(connection))
```

If you'd like to see everything in a given table, you could do something like this now:

```
from ibm_db import exec_immediate

sql = 'LIST * FROM ' + t[170]['TABLE_NAME']  # Using our list of tables t from before...
rows = results(exec_immediate(connection, sql))
```

And now `rows` contains a `list` of rows from the 170th table in your database, where every row contains a `dict` of column name: value.

Hope this all helps.

Comment: I'm getting SQLCODE=-104 for the line:

rows = results(exec_immediate(connection, sql))
Any idea what's causing this error?

Comment: @crh878 - [The IBM DB2 documentation says `SQLCODE=-104` means you have an illegal symbol or token.](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n104.html) I suggest you `print(sql)` on the line before, then copy and paste that output in another comment here if you can't see what's wrong for yourself.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be like:

sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + t[170]['TABLE_NAME']

Comment: @daixtr - Hm... IDK. I don't work with DB2 anymore, so I can't verify whether `LIST` is a valid command or not. Maybe it's a typo and I meant `SELECT`. If you have a DB2 instance to check with, maybe you can verify and then edit my answer (or just tell me in the comments and I can edit it, if you don't have enough rep to do it yourself.)

Answer (score 17):

After lots of digging I discovered how to connect with DB2 using ibm_db.

First off, if you use a python version higher than 3.2 use

> pip install ibm_db==2.0.8a

version 2.0.8 (the latest) will fail to install.

then use the following to connect

```
import ibm_db_dbi as db

conn = db.connect("DATABASE=name;HOSTNAME=host;PORT=60000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password;", "", "")
```

list tables with

```
for t in conn.tables():
    print(t)
```

and execute SQL with

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Schema.Table")
for r in cursor.fetchall():
    print(r)
```

check [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/c0054699.html) for official not so accurate documentation

Comment: Honestly, I'm upvoting this just for the 2.0.8a tip alone. I can't verify the connection string because I don't have the driver used by ibm_db. I do have an ODBC driver which is suitable for pyodbc, so that's what I actually use.

Answer (score 11):

ibm-db, the official DB2 driver for Python and Django is here:

- https://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/

Here's a recent tutorial for how to install everything on Ubuntu Linux:

- http://programmingzen.com/2011/05/12/installing-python-django-and-db2-on-ubuntu-11-04/

I should mention that there were several older unofficial DB2 drivers for Python. ibm-db is the one you should be using.

Comment: It is outdated. It also needs IBM_DB_DI and ibm_db which takes tremendous amount of work to be installed. Classic IBM clumsiness.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @prof1990 [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119068/10967295):

Since 2.0.9 (Aug 16th 2018), also with Python 3 you can simply use:

```
pip install ibm_db
```

Reference:

https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb#updated-ibm_db

Example of connection [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054368.html):

```
import ibm_db
ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=<dbname>;HOSTNAME=<host>;PORT=<60000>;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>;", "", "")
```

Full API documentation here:

https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to db2 from python using jaydeapi
First install library running pip install jaydeapi
download db2jcc4.jar
Then you can connect using below code :
by passing hostname,portno, userid,password database name

```
import jaydebeapi

conn_src = jaydebeapi.connect(
    'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver',
    ['YourHostName:PortNo/DatabaseName','userid','password'],'C:/db2jcc4.jar'
)

cursor=conn_src.cursor()
sql = 'Select * from schemaname.TableName fetch first 100 rows only '

cursor.execute(sql)
print("fetchall:")
result = cursor.fetchall()
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way in which one can connect to IBM db2 using nothing but Python requests library. Worked for me.

**STEP 1:**
Go to IBM CLOUD Dashboard -> Navigate to your IBM db2 instance -> Click on 'Service Credentials'
A default one should be there, if not, create one. This service credential is a dictionary. Copy the service credentials.
**STEP 2:**

```
db2id = { // service credential dictionary here //}
api = "/dbapi/v3"
host = db2id['https_url']+api
userinfo = {"userid":db2id['username'],"password":db2id['password']}
service = '/auth/tokens'
r = requests.post(host+service,json=userinfo)
access_token = r.json()['token']
auth_header = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+access_token}

// Connection to database established
```

**STEP 3**
Now you can run SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE queries
The format for INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE queries is the same. After an INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE query, a COMMIT query has to be sent, else changes aren't reflected. (You should commit your changes otherwise also)

**INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE QUERIES**

```
sql = " your insert/update/delete query here "
sql_command = {"commands":sql,"limit":1000,"separator":";","stop_on_error":"yes"}
service = "/sql_jobs"
r = requests.post(host+service,headers=auth_header,json=sql_command)
sql_command = {"commands":"COMMIT","limit":1000,"separator":";","stop_on_error":"yes"}
service = "/sql_jobs"
r = requests.post(host+service,headers=auth_header,json=sql_command)
```

You can use the variable r to check status of your request

**SELECT QUERIES**

```
sql = " your select query here "
service = "/sql_jobs"
r = requests.post(host+service,headers=auth_header,json=sql_command)
jobid = r.json()['id']
r = requests.get(host+service+"/"+jobid,headers=auth_header)
results = r.json()['results']
rows = results[0]['rows']
```

The variable **rows** will have the results of your query. Use it as per your convenience.

I didn't use any DDL queries. But I think they should work like the DML queries. Not sure though!

Comment: While this link can provide an answer to the question, it is necessary to add all info needed to the answer, if the linked content gets removed by time, your answer should still be informative.

Comment: @Ruli the video has been there since 2018, don't think it will be removed. Will try to include info in the answer :)

Comment: The video has been removed and the info isn't in the answer, so...

Answer (score 1):

IBM's Db2 is available for various platforms. If you are trying to connect to a Db2 which lives on an IBM i server (formerly known as AS/400, iSeries, or System i), then ibm_db requires a product called [*Db2 Connect*](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/db2-connect), which is rather expensive. Most people who use Python to connect to Db2 for i use ODBC (usually through [PyODBC](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/)).

I'm not completely sure about the situation with Db2 on their z (mainframe) servers, but I would think it also requires Db2 Connect.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to connect from Python to Db2. I am trying to provide a summary of options. Note that in many environments SSL/TLS is enforced now which requires additional parameters (see below).

##### Db2 and Python drivers

Db2 does not offer one, but four drivers (clients) for Python. The [Db2 documentation page "Python, SQLAlchemy, and Django Framework application development for IBM Database servers"](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=applications-python-sqlalchemy-django-framework) provides a good overview about the four drivers:

- [ibm_db](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) is based on the IBM-defined API,
- [ibm_db_dbi](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) is a driver for the Python database API (DBI),
- [ibm_db_sa](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa) implements the Python [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) interface and
- [ibm_db_django](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django) serves as Db2 driver in the Django Framework.

Note that there are additional Python database interfaces which make use of existing JDBC or ODBC drivers which can be used to connect to Db2. You can use SQLAlchemy (ibm_db_sa) with the popular [Flask framework](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/). To use Db2 with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) utilize ibm_db_dbi. All of the above [Db2 drivers are available on GitHub](https://github.com/ibmdb/) and are based on the CLI (Call Level Interface / ODBC). There are additional ways to connect to Db2, e.g., by using 3rd party ODBC-based wrappers and more.

##### Db2 connections

Typical connection information is made up of the Db2 server (hostname), the port, the database name and username / password information. If nothing else is specified, most drivers assume that the connection is not encrypted. Thus, to connect over an encrypted connection more parameters are needed. They depend on the Db2 version, the type of Db2 product and some more. Let's start easy.

[Newer Db2 versions simplified the use of SSL/TLS because certificates are now part of the package](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=ctsidc-configuring-tls-support-in-non-java-db2-clients). A typical connection string would then look like this:

```
conn_str='database=MYDB;hostname=db2host.example.com;port=50001;protocol=tcpip;uid=db2inst1;pwd=secret;security=SSL'

ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str,'','')
```

An important parameter is "security=SSL" to tell the driver to use [encryption for the data in transit](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=model-data-encryption#c0005815__tls_not_ssl).

Db2 connection strings can have even more options. It depends on what security plugin is enabled. See this blog post on [connecting from Python to Db2](https://blog.4loeser.net/2021/07/how-to-connect-from-python-to-db2.html) for more links and discussions.

#### SQL Alchemy connection

When using Db2 with SQLAlchemy, pass an URI similar to

ibm_db_sa://user:password@hostname:port/database?Security=SSL

to get the connection established.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I successfully connected IBM DB2 from Python and retrieved the results.

#### Issue:

When I tried to install `pip install ibm-db`, I got this error:

```
pip install ibm-db
running build_ext
building 'ibm_db' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for ibm-db
Failed to build ibm-db
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ibm-db, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

#### Solution:

1. I found the below steps from https://python-forum.io/thread-38681.html

   ```
   G:\div_code\answer
   λ python -m venv ibm_env

   G:\div_code\answer
   λ cd ibm_env\

   G:\div_code\answer\ibm_env
   λ G:\div_code\answer\ibm_env\Scripts\activate

   (ibm_env) G:\div_code\answer\ibm_env
   λ pip install ibm-db
   ```
2. I copied the below folders/files from `ibm_env\Lib\site-packages` to my python installed `Python36\Lib\site-packages`

   ```
   ibm_db
   ibm_db_dbi
   certs (Folder)
   clidriver (Folder)
   ibm_db_dlls (Folder)
   ibm_db_tests (Folder)
   ibm_db-3.1.3-py3.6.egg-info (Folder)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ibm_db library to connect DB2.

```
query_str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name"

conn = ibm_db.pconnect("dsn=write","usrname","secret")
query_stmt   = ibm_db.prepare(conn, query_str)
ibm_db.execute(query_stmt)
```

Comment: How do we get the `ibm_db` library?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, just import it. `pip install ibm_db`

Answer (score 0):

This is for future reference:

[Official installation docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.python.doc/doc/t0054367.html) say:

> Python 2.5 or later, excluding Python 3.X.

```
pip install ibm_db
```

It only worked on Python 2.7 for me; it didn't for 3.X. Also, I had to make Python 2.7 default (instead of Python 3) so that the installation would work (otherwise, there would be installation errors).

[Official docs sample usage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054368.html):

```
import ibm_db 
ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=name;HOSTNAME=host;PORT=60000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username; PWD=password;", "", "")
```

Comment: this answer is still partially correct, however things have changed and ibm_db now supports up to 3.6.5 when using the right version, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Version: ibm-db 3.0.2 - `ibm-db==3.0.2`

```
pip install ibm-db
```

Released: Jun 17, 2020

Connect to a local or cataloged database:

```
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("database","username","password")
```

Connect to an uncataloged database:

```
import ibm_db
ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=name;HOSTNAME=host;PORT=60000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;
            PWD=password;", "", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

How I managed to do in 2021.
What you will need:

- Python 3.7
- PipEnv
- Ibm-db

Ibm-db version is not important but this lib only works with Python 3.7 (current python version is 3.9).

Install Python 3.7.6 in your machine (this is the version that worked).

In your IDE create a new python file.

**Let' create a Virtual Enviroment** to make sure we will use Python 3.7

```
pip install pipenv
```

After installing

```
pipenv install --python 3.7
```

Activate the Virtual Environment

```
pipenv shell
```

You can use `pip list` to verify if you are in the new Virtual Enviroment - if list only shows 3 or 4 libs, it's because you are

**Now you can download Ibm_db**

```
pip install ibm-db
```

You may add this to your code to confirm what is the version you are using

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

**Now accessing the DB2**

```
import ibm_db_dbi as db

# Connect to DB2B1 (keep Protocol as TCPIP)
conn = db.connect("DATABASE=DBNAME;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=Your User;PWD=Your Password;", "", "")
```

Checking all tables available

```
for t in conn.tables():
    print(t)
```

Your SQL code:

```
sql_for_df = """SELECT *
                FROM TABLE
                WHERE ..."""
```

**Visualizing as DataFrame**

First install pandas as it will not be present in your Virtual Environment

```
pip install pandas
```

After that import to your code and play around

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_sql(sql_for_df, conn) 
df.head()
```

To exit the VIrtual Enviroment just write `exit` in your terminal.
If you want to remove the Virtual Enviroment write in the terminal `pipenv --rm`

That's pretty much all I could learn so far.
I hope it helps you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Install : ibm_db package
# Command : pip install ibm_db

import ibm_db
import sys


def get_connection():
    db_name = ""
    db_host_name = ""
    db_port = ""
    db_protocol = ""
    db_username = ""
    db_password = ""

    try:
        conn = ibm_db.connect(
        f"DATABASE = {db_name}; HOSTNAME = {db_host_name}; PORT = {db_port}; PROTOCOL = {db_protocol}; "
        f"UID = {db_username}; PWD = {db_password};", "", "")
        return conn
    except:
        print("no connection:", ibm_db.conn_errormsg())
        sys.exit(1)

get_connection()
```