# Getting chained/piped commands result to shell variable

Tags: bash, unix, db2, pipeline

Given a db2 proc call's output:

```
$ db2 "call SOME_PROC(103,5,0,'','',0,0)"

  Return Status = 0
```

I wish to just get the value and when I 'chain-em-up' it does not work as I think it should, so given:

```
$ db2 "call SOME_PROC(103,5,0,'','',0,0)" | sed -rn 's/ *Return Status *= *([0-9]+)/\1/p'
0
```

I try to chain 'em up:

```
$ var=$(db2 "call SOME_PROC(103,5,0,'','',0,0)" | sed -rn 's/ *Return Status *= *([0-9]+)/\1/p')
$ echo $var
```

You get nothin !

But if you redirect to tmp file:

```
$ db2 "call SOME_PROC(103,5,0,'','',0,0)" > /tmp/fff
$ var=$(cat /tmp/fff | sed -rn 's/ *Return Status *= *([0-9]+)/\1/p')
$ echo $var
0
```

You **do** get it ...

Similarly if you put in var:

```
$ var=$(db2 "call DB2INST1.USP_SPOTLIGHT_GET_DATA(103,5,0,'','',0,0)")
$ var=$(echo $var | sed -rn 's/ *Return Status *= *([0-9]+)/\1/p')
$ echo $var
0
```

You also get it ...

Is there a way to get value as my first attempt? And also I wonder why does it not work? What am I missing?

I also tried the below and it also givs nothing!

```
cat <(db2 -x "call DB2INST1.USP_SPOTLIGHT_GET_DATA(103,5,0,'','',0,0)" | sed -rn 's/ *Return Status *= *([0-9]+)/\1/p')
```

Comment: If you want to do something complicated with db2, you are probably better off using a scripting language which has a db2 interface. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044326/how-to-connect-python-to-db2 will be helpful. (I've never used it, but I found it with an SO search.)

Comment: I think the problem is that `$(db2 "call whatever..." | sed .. )` is launched in a new shell, where the database connection does not exist. You probably need to do something like `$(db2 connect ...>/dev/null; db2 call...)`

Comment: @mustaccio: To me if `cmd | cmd` gives output then `var=$(cmd | cmd)` should set that output to `$var`. Your explanation, I think, does not apply to my question

Comment: I don't know what is going on here, but it seems possible that the `sed` command is throwing away useful information.  If you run `var=$(db2 "call SOME_PROC(103,5,0,'','',0,0)" | cat) ; declare -p var`, what output do you get?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself properly. I'll try again. `db2 call...` requires an established database connection, which is local to the shell instance. Once you stick it into `$(db2 call...)` you spawn a new shell, where the connection does not exist. You can see this yourself: create a shell function `function mybashpid { echo $BASHPID; }`, then run it as `mybashpid` and as `echo $(mybashpid)`, you will see that the latter runs in a new shell. If you do `echo $(db2 call ... 2>&1)` you will see that it prints an error instead of your procedure output.

Comment: Yep @mustaccio, now I understand it, I also add for extra measure `echo $BASH_SUBSHELL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db2` command-line interface requires that the `db2` command be issued as a direct child of the parent of the command which initiated the connection. In other words, the `db2 call` and `db2 connect` commands need to be initiated from the same shell process.

That does not interact well with many shell features:

- pipelines: `cmd1 | cmd2` runs both commands in subshells (different processes).
- command substitution: `$(cmd)` runs the command in a subshell.
- process substitution (bash): `<(cmd)` runs the command in a subshell.

However, if the shell is bash, the situation is not quite that restricted, so under some circumstances the above constructions will still work with `db2`. In pipelines and command substitution, bash will optimize away the subshell if the command to be run in the subshell is simple enough. (Roughly speaking, it must be a simple command without redirects.)

So, for example, if some bash process *P* executes

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

then both commands have *P* as their parent, because they are both simple commands. Similarly with

```
a=$(cmd)
```

However, if a pipelined command or a substituted command is not simple, then a subshell is required. For example, even though `{ ...}` does not require a subshell, the syntax is not a simple command. So in

```
{ cmd1; } | cmd2
```

the first command is a child of a subshell, while the second command is a child of the main shell.

In particular, in

```
a=$(cmd1 | cmd2)
```

bash will not optimize away the command-substitution subshell, because `cmd1 | cmd2` is not a simple command. So it will create a subshell to execute the pipeline; that subshell will apply the optimization, so there will not be additional subshells to execute the simple commands `cmd1` and `cmd2`.

In short, you can pipeline the output of `db2 call` or you can capture the output in a variable, but you cannot capture the output of a pipeline in a variable.

---

Other shells are more (or less) capable of subshell optimizations. With `zsh`, for example, you can use process substitution to avoid the subshell:

```
# This will work with zsh but not with bash
var=$(db2 "call ..." > >(sed -rn ...))
```

The syntax `cmd1 > >(cmd2)` is very similar to the pipeline `cmd1 | cmd2`, but it differs in that is syntactically a simple command. For zsh, that is sufficient to allow the elimination of the subshell (but not for bash, which won't optimize away a subshell if the command involves a redirection).

Comment: Possibly, like how one segment of a pipeline runs in the current shell too.

Comment: @Etan: A more precise explanation of the bash optimization. Unfortunately, the `cmd1 > >(cmd2)` trick doesn't work because the redirect is enough to avoid the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

As @rici so briliantly explained it all, I just wanna show it live:

With `cmd | cmd` you get:

```
$ db2 "call SOME_PROC(103,5,0,'','',0,0)" | cat

  Return Status = 0
```

But with `{cmd ;} | cmd` you get:

```
$ { db2 "call SOME_PROC(103,5,0,'','',0,0)" ;} | cat
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
```