# Failure while connecting to IBM DB2 database from my Python Flask API's

Tags: python, flask, db2, connection-pooling

I need help with an issue which I am facing.

This is the error message I get:

> Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30020N  Execution of the command or SQL statement failed because of a syntax error in the communication data stream that will affect the successful execution of subsequent commands and SQL statements:  Reason Code "0x124C"("0214")"".  SQLSTATE=58009 SQLCODE=-30020

This is an intermittent issue which I face when running my API's.

Can someone please help me understand what is causing this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: [this may help](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005q8CR9CAM/i-am-getting-a-syntax-error-message-when-trying-to-connecton-to-db2-on-as400-with-nodejs?language=en_US)

Comment: Hi @sahasrara62, i did see this page but it doesn't have any clear resolution. I face the above error message 20-30% of the times and the API works perfectly the remaining time. I am using the package ibm-db-sa in my code, is there something i am missing?

Comment: Connecting to DB2 using [`ibm_db` python library](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054368.html). Also see this: [How to connect Python to Db2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044326/how-to-connect-python-to-db2). This may help, but partially.

Comment: Usually this symptom is configuration related. Your question has zero details about your configuration. EDIT your question (do not use comments to add facts), to add: (1) your Db2-server operating system (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows, and the Db2-server version/modificiation/release (2) your client side operating system, name/release/edition, (3) the name and version of the Db2-driver that you are using on the client side.