# Python code to list the active database from IBM UDB DB2

Tags: python, db2

Could someone please help me in getting the list of active databases through python code from IBM DB2

Comment: please check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044326/how-to-connect-python-to-db2)

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do it, but here is an example that uses a monitoring query. Your userid needs appropriate authorisation to run the query, refer to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-snap-get-db) for details.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# the shell session that runs this script needs
# the correct environment variables to be already set
# (usually by dotting in the correct db2profile for the Db2 instance)
# otherwise ibm_db will fail to import citing load failure
# on a db2 library.
#
import sys
import ibm_db

db_user=''
db_name='sample'
db_pwd=''

try:
    ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(db_name, db_user, db_pwd)
except:
    print('Failed to connect to database' + db_name)
    print(ibm_db.conn_errormsg())
    sys.exit(1)

try:
   action='Query snap_get_db'
   active_databases_query="SELECT db_name FROM TABLE(snap_get_db(NULL))"
   stmt_handle = ibm_db.exec_immediate(ibm_db_conn, active_databases_query)
   if  stmt_handle :
       action = 'Fetching resultSet returned by query'
       row = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt_handle)
       while (row ):
          for i in row:
              print(i)
          row = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(stmt_handle)
   
except:
   print('Failed on ' + action)
   print(ibm_db.errormsg())
   sys.exit(1)
```